# What is the difference in usage of "go on", "carry on", "keep on"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, synonyms

My dictionary gives all of the "go on", "carry on", "keep on" as the same synonym for "continue". There was no difference to me till now. I need to write a sentence like:

> We have decided to [carry/keep/go] on using free version of this software.

And [go on] does not sound comfortable to me in this case. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

> go on

is often gets used to spur someone or something to *start*.

> Don't wait for us, *go on* ahead.

In your case you are continuing to do something

> keep on *(AmE)*
>   carry on *(BrE, AmE)*

are both appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Basically they mean the same thing, but in some contexts one usage is more common. The best choice is really context dependent.

> That is a great story. **Go on**.

and

> Q. Am I doing this correctly?
>   A. Yes you are. **Carry on**.

and

> I asked her to go out with me, but she only laughs. But I will **keep on** trying.